QField: NMEA serial connection issues
I am trying to connect QField to a BT serial port that is receiving NMEA stream from a GNSS receiver.
QField is running on a Panasonic FZ-G1 running Windows 10.
Both QGIS and puTTY are able to receive the NMEA stream.
When trying to connect QField I get the following error:

Positioning device error: Connection was refused due to not having enough permission

I made sure QGIS and puTTY are not grabbing the port and tried to ensure nothing else has the port locked.
Does anyone have any tips?

run qfield as admin should work.

Run as admin on windows did the trick.

run qfield as admin should work. –
Mapperz
♦
CommentedAug 1 at 13:37
This did work.  Now I just need it to work on an Android.

Feel free to create another question for the Android issue.

I did here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/487467/253842
