How to enable NMEA streaming from external bluetooth device on Android
I am trying to enable NMEA streamed data within qField for Android.
I have a Leica GS16 GNSS receiver with NMEA streaming output via bluetooth enabled.
I am able to connect to and receive the NMEA data in both QGIS and QField on my laptop via a bluetooth serial port IFF I start the applications in administration mode.
I am able to connect to the GS16 via bluetooth in QField on the Android.  However, the NMEA data is not available.  I have granted all permissions to QField in Android.
If I need to route through a serial port on the Android, then how do I do this?
Using up-to-date Android 14 on S22 Ultra running QField 3.4.4 - Ebo
The image below is of QField running as administrator in Windows 10 connected to the GS16 using NMEA data through a Bluetooth Serial port.


Can you explain why you want to see the NMEA?

I am connecting to an external GNSS receiver that can utilize RTK corrections and has better positional capability than the android.

I don't use Leica GNSS or qfield so I can't answer the question, I suspect this is a procedure problem.
In Android, the common method for an app to get positions from an external GNSS is to use an Android app from the GNSS manufacturer (maybe Leica Zeno Connect for the GS16) to feed positions into Android Location services, then consume those positions in your Android app the same way you'd use positions from the internal GNSS receiver.
